# Migration from Ant to Maven with OSGI?

Tags: java, maven, ant, osgi, apache-karaf

I am migrating an old project from Ant to Maven. The project should consists of several projects bundled together and must be OSGI. It use to be Ant built in such a way as to be OSGI. I am using the Eclipse IDE.

1. Is it possible to Run Ant from Maven and also make sure it is OSGI? I could find some examples about running Ant from Maven (Maven AntRun Plugin) but couldn't find anything with also OSGI mentioned.
2. The other option is to use Karaf to bundle the Maven projects. Is is complicated to use Karaf?

Thank you

Comment: You should take a look into https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/osgi/osgi-test/tree/main/examples/osgi-test-example-mvn for an example of a set of OSGi projects, including testing, using Maven and the Bnd Maven plugins.